# Are you interested in beta testing games?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Yesterday, Alex Miller [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100819/are-you-an-android-apple-or-game-developer-looking-for-beta-testers) over on Meta.SO about a potential match-making service between our developer and user communities (namely Android, Apple and gaming enthusiasts). You can check out his original post, but the gist of it is that we have great developers and user communities on the site, and connecting the two could be an awesome opportunity for all involved. A program like this would be completely free and strictly opt-in for both developers and beta testers.

So, who would be interested in a program like this if we get enough interest to launch it?

Comment: Obviously do want! :D Then again, how much public Q&A could we do about the game in the process?

Comment: me would be interested

Comment: +1 - Definitely caught my interest.

Comment: I'd definitely be interested.

Comment: Absolutely; as @badp asks, I'd like to know if we'd be restricted by some sort of NDA (which wouldn't be optimal, but I'm not saying no either way)

Comment: Is this really very different than [this question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/community-promotional-grant-movement-closed-beta-system)

Comment: @Raven, if I understand correctly, the difference is that the new initiative is aimed at a wider group of games: not just high-profile games, but any games that SO users are designing.

Comment: I would also be highly interested in this!

Comment: @Raven I think that in this case there is no need (or even no permission) to ask and answer questions about these games during the beta.

Comment: @Raven I think the ultimate goal here is for GSE to act as the support for games the way SO acts as the support for many open source projects.  On an unrelated not I think it would be interesting

Comment: An additional option, if SO hosts an exchange like this might be to set up a private StackExchange for private beta test questions, which at the end of the term would get migrated (with perhaps some moderation for fixed bugs) into the main site?

Comment: Additionally, I see this has been raised over at SO, and at Apple/Android.SE and here, but why not over at [GameDev](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/)? Given that we're the *users* being reached out to, it'd probably be wise to reach out to the Devs most closely linked to the products we use.

Comment: Could be an rather interesting way of using all these SE communities that happen to be lying around to help one another, you've got my interest.

Comment: absolutely, do it up

Comment: This sounds awesome, I'd be in.

Comment: absolutely, it will also be a good opportunity to get in some early gaming questions if no NDA is required

Comment: Yep, this sounds like it could be interesting.

Comment: Count me in, definitely interested!

Comment: @LessPop, I've reached out to gamedev.se to get the ball rolling. There'll be updates here as soon as we have some games for y'all to test!

Comment: Yep, you can check out this topic's development over at [Game Development](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/533/its-time-for-us-to-bring-the-chaos-to-game-development). The ball is rolling!

Comment: @BrettWhiteΨ oh nooo it's rolling into the streeeet

Comment: Any news from here?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a Google doc for those of you that are interested! Hurrah! Please fill out this [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?hl=en_US&formkey=dFFOUWFsVWo5R3lNVUlScHJVZTQxRkE6MQ#gid=0) with your information and the match-making process with gaming developers will begin when they are ready. You can also take a gander at the [discussion on Game Dev's Meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/533/its-time-for-us-to-bring-the-chaos-to-game-development), so you can get an idea of what's happening on their end.

If you have any questions about this process, please leave them in the comments (right? does that make sense?). Thanks!

Comment: I notice there's no question about which region of console you own on the google doc. Will it have no relevance at all to the future testing? We have people with Japanese, North American, and European/Australian consoles on the site, and it'd suck if a group got locked out.

Comment: I believe that Chaos Agent Abby edited the doc to reflect this. If it's still missing this info, let us know. Thanks!

Comment: What should I do if I filled it out prior to the change? Re-submit?

Comment: You can resubmit if you want to.