# Is it appropriate to seek alpha/beta testers at the site?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, specific-question

My goal with my project is a space shooter inspired by games such as Tachyon: The Fringe, Battlezone 1-2, Freelancer, Homeworld, Elite and such space environments. I built a ["pre-alpha" release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spaceworld/). Now I seek feedback and testers for wIntel platform and Apple and Ubuntu testers (since the program [fails to update the display on Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311415/how-to-handle-a-java-7-lwjgl-shader-exception) due to some graphics rendering). Can I ask for general and specific feedback, testers and their opinion about my game project and whether it is beyond the "pre-alpha" stage or not even there, for instance what is the worst problem, should the project be considered a beta instead of a pre-alpha, an alpha now that it got some features, what to consider be the core functionality that must work, when the ideas are many:

TODO: 
  Mac compatibility, trading with the space station. collision detection for moons and planets
  more realistic atmosphere entry, houses and cities on planets, robots like Oto on the moon that can build new robots
  beam stuff up from the surface with the white construction,  a black hole somewhere?
  multiplayer so that you can meet in space, jumpgate teleporting FX
  landing on planets and moons, the UFO should be able to rotate.

[image]

Comment: You could always try the [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something we had shown interest in a few months ago:

[Are you interested in beta testing games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/are-you-interested-in-beta-testing-games)

I think that I wouldn't have a problem with politely asking for help on chat — do remember that'd everything there is publicly logged and indexed by search engines — or politely getting in touch with people who have elected to publish private contact information on their public SE profiles.

Comment: That's from a few *years* ago.

Answer (score 1):

No, you may not use Arqade to recruit testers, gather opinions, or discuss your game.  Arqade is about asking questions, and getting definitive answers, as is the entire SE network.  What you're asking for runs counter to that entire premise.

What you're asking for is essentially ideas for game development.  There's no way to provide anything approaching knowledgeable or authoritive answers whatsoever. We specifically have a close reason for exactly those types of questions: Primarily opinion based.

We don't mind questions that require at least *some* opinion, backed up by facts from in-game.  In fact, those tend to be the best questions Arqade gets.  But questions that just ask for an opinion are completely off-topic, because there is no right answer.  The entire SE network refuses those sorts of questions.

A good rule of thumb is: Can a question be answered using the information gained within a game?  If yes, then chances are good we'll allow it.  Outside of that is pretty risky, and needs to meet some very strict criteria in order to be allowed here.

Comment: I don't quite think he was going to ask for help in the form of a question on Arqade...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found that I probably should keep the release as pre-alpha or alpha when I read that "beta releases are mostly finished" and I don't consider my project "mostly finished", in fact I want to set feasible goals so that it fulfils the requirement "game" and not only simulation or so. I aim at 2-player space shooter and limited health by number of shots at your craft, so that 2 players actually can play and one win.