# Is it ok to ask poll-type questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, poll

The question I want to ask is:

> Title: [poll] Would you switch to a pay-as-you-go game server hosting service?
>
> Tag: poll, hosting, minecraft-server
>
> Body:
>
> The goal is to make game server hosting cheaper by paying only for the time gamers are using the server.
>   My research shows that the last time someone took a shot at this is [back in 2011](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2581798).
>   I reached out to the OP a few days ago, and it turned out that he never built it because he was too busy with a full-time job, some freelancing, and writing a book.
>   Before I dive into building such a service, I'd like to consult the Arqade community if this is of any use at all.
>   I built https://horae.net over the past week to give you something to toy around with. It only does minecraft servers ATM, the server creation is still manual, but the server start/stop and billing is self-serve already.
>
> Would you switch for this?
>
> If yes, please sign up on https://horae.net so I can update you on progress.
>
> If not, is there anything that would change your mind? Or is this a fundamentally flawed idea?

Before I ask permission on meta here, I did some research and found:

- [How should one ask polling questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/how-should-one-ask-polling-questions) on meta.stackexchange.com:
  It's 10 years old but asks the same question I'm asking here.
- [Are you interested in beta testing games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/are-you-interested-in-beta-testing-games) on gaming.meta.stackexchange.com:
  It covers how I'm a developer looking for feedback from the arqade user community,
  albeit aimed at beta testing and cross-community growth by [the now-defunct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257699/why-did-the-chaos-programme-stop) CHAOS team.
- [stackoverflow advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/): the minimum advertising fee is $10k... way-out-of-budget.
- [SO Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): literally states "Avoid overt self-promotion.", but I'm not sure if my post would be "overt"

So:

- meta question 1: Are poll-type questions in general on arqade ok?
- meta question 2: Is my specific poll-type question ok to post? Of course I'm open to changes to make it ok.
- meta question 3: If poll-type questions are ok, and if I have another poll-type question, should I always get permission for it here on meta first?

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely a question that would be off-topic for this site.

1. It has several of the red flags listed on our [Don't Ask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help page, specifically "Every answer is equally valid" and "There is no actual problem being solved".
2. The topic is not listed in our [on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) list.
3. We decided pretty early on that [poll questions aren't allowed in Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/should-we-allow-poll-questions)

   - Poll type questions in general are not a good fit for Arqade - or any other SE site, as far as I know. Polls just don't mesh with the Q+A format.
4. I feel like you're definitely advertising too much. The only necessary info needed to ask this question would the purpose of the site you've built; you don't need link your page or even mention the name. Not only are you be doing that, but you've also got a call to action that requests people join the site. It really feels like the whole point of the question isn't even to gather info, but to spread awareness of your site to get clicks.

For these reasons, I think the question you've proposed is off topic and would quickly be closed as such.

Comment: What if I just say "Would you switch to a pay-as-you-go game server hosting service?" and nothing else?

Comment: @shadi, that would be closed as primarily opinion based

Comment: Actually never mind me. It's probably still a no because it's a poll. Thanks!